# PHP Short If Statment with OR

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following PHP script

```
<?php 
    echo (($statusSet) == 'all') ? "class='selected'": "";
?>
```

What I would like to do is include an OR into this to say where $statusSet is equal to all OR NULL

Im competely lost with hwo to write this as I tried adding the normal type of OR statement which didnt work

```
<?php 
    echo ((($statusSet) == 'all')||(($statusSet) == 'all'))) ? "class='selected'": "";
?>
```

Comment: Whats up with all the Parentheses? I could understand putting Parentheses around an IF statement where its not needed, but around a single variable? Are you afraid php thinks `Set` isnt part of `$statusSet` because its capitalized?

Comment: Why is everyone against parentheses?  They can be great for grouping logic and making code clearer.  If you don't like them, that's fine... but it's stupid to suggest that are in some way bad.

Comment: if your php version is new enough: `echo !in_array($statusSet, array('all', null)) ?: 'class="selected"';` will also do, and opens the possibility for easily adding more values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you're doing is adding another expression to be evaluated in the overall if statement.

```
<?php echo (($statusSet == 'all' || $statusSet === null) ? "class='selected'": ""); ?>
```

Someone below posted a nearly-identical snippet to mine, but used **is_null()** instead.  Note that using **is_null()** or **=== null** is fine, but using **== null** isn't best practices - it won't ensure type equality so if $statusSet was set to (int)0, doing **$statusSet == null** would return true when it's actually not a null value.

Comment: what's with everyone's parentheses today? :) you can remove all your grouping $statusSet == 'all' || $statusSet === null ? "class='selected'": ""; will work just fine.

Comment: Sure, you could omit them.  Given the OP's lack of full understanding of logical expressions, I figured it prudent to use parentheses to indicate that everything in the parentheses was the logical expression... that you don't need to wrap each condition in double parentheses, etc.  It's more for clarity and demonstration... obviously they aren't required but neither is any whitespace at all... that'd be terribly ugly, though. :)

Comment: Now, this is what i don't understand. Why null === null evaluates true.

Comment: @itachi Because null DOES EQUAL null

Comment: @itachi === is the type/value equality operator.  null is the exact same type/value as null, so it evaluates true.  In the eyes of PHP, 0 and null are equal.. but only if you don't care about type... PHP dumbs the values down internally to a point where they represent "nothing," essentially, so null == 0 would evaluate true... but 0 obviously isn't null.  This is why you use the === operator.

Comment: @TobyLawrence that is true, but he shall learn much faster if we show him the way. :)

Comment: @TobyLawrence: i get about the operator. But null means an unknown unique value which can be equal to itself only and NOT another null value. So if $a is null, $b is null, they shouldn't necessarily be equal. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @itachi think of null as an location in memory; when a variable is declared without a value or is assigned null the value of that variable is a reference to null and therefore is exactly the same so therefore must be of the same type and value.

Answer (score 2):

So like this?

```
echo $statusSet == 'all' || $statusSet === NULL ? "class='selected'": "";?>
```

I'm not sure that you copied the correct line into the question, but the reason that yours isn't working is because the two conditions are exactly the same, hence if one is true then then so is the other.

Comment: You're missing an opening parenthesis for the second condition. :)

Comment: Not neccessary my friend, in fact none of them are.. See my edit.

Comment: If you use them, but don't have the right number, it's a compilation error.  So actually.. you did in fact need another one until you removed them entirely. :)

Comment: Really? I thought I counted an even number.. Ah well, if you were correct, well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo (($statusSet == 'all') || (is_null($statusSet)) ) ? "class='selected'": "";?>
```

Comment: you forgot your $ on the second $statusSet variable